# Getting all modules loaded into a process and then getting their exports

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllexport

I have a DLL and I'm trying to get all modules in a process without using GetModuleHandle and then getting exports without using GetProcAddress... I read a little into the PEB structure and PEB_LDR_DATA, but I'm not sure if this is the right path. The reason why I can't use those is that they take in a const char* argument, while I need to compare by hash of the string rather than by the string itself.

Comment: Why not use the API for this?

Comment: Most API functions that do this, which I know of require you to pass in a const char*. Also, api calls can be intercepted quite easily.

Comment: So what. What is the problem with that.

Comment: I need to compare hashes and get the module handle as well as its exports by hash. I need to do it manually.

Comment: Module32First/Module32Next not use name as input arguments. so you can use it

Comment: I would rather avoid using WINAPI. I updated my posts with my current status. Not sure if I'm getting the handle correctly...

Comment: you code valid only for x86. for x64 need `__readgsqword(FIELD_OFFSET(_TEB, ProcessEnvironmentBlock))` or `__readgsqword(0x60)` - `avoid using WINAPI` - why ?

Comment: I'm working with x86 so that's not currently a problem. I'm trying to avoid WINAPI in order to be as stealth in the process memory as possible as it will be undergoing manual reverse engineering analysis. Is my way of getting the handle valid on both x86 and x64?

Comment: The winapi tag is somewhat misleading then.

Comment: I changed it. I figured it would be applicable as I was asking for help with an alternative to a few WINAPI functions. Anyways, having the handle now how should I go about finding an export without GetProcAddress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, walking the list in `PEB_LDR_DATA` will give you all the loaded modules but you should at least try the documented [`Module32First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684218(v=vs.85).aspx) function first. Walking the list without holding the loader-lock can be risky.

Once you know the module base address you examine the export directory after parsing your way there in the [PE file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#External_links).

Comment: Is there a way to simply get the pointer to the LDR_DATA_ENTRY so I can walk the list of the modules without using inline asm?

Comment: so I'm able to do this? PEB* peb_ = (PEB*)__readfsdword(0x30); and then go from there to find the first entry in the list?

Comment: You can try to acquire and release the loader lock using the undocumented `LdrLockLoaderLock` and `LdrUnlockLoaderLock` functions from NTDLL, or go through the `PEB_LDR_DATA` from the `DllMain` of a dedicated DLL (while refraining from calling almost any other interesting API).